# fread not working while reading structure dynamically from a file

Tags: c, struct, fwrite, fread, file-handling

I am creating a linked list then writing it to a file and reading it again. I am using fwrite and fread to write and read a whole instance of a structure at a time. But the problem is it is not working correctly. I suppose writing is working fine after seeing the output file but still not sure about it. But reading is not working at all.

Below is structure

```
struct student
{
int roll_num;
char name[100];
struct student *next;
};
```

Below is logic

```
ifd = fopen("qwer1234.txt","wb");
struct student *temp;
temp = start;
while(temp != NULL)
{
    fwrite(temp, sizeof(struct student), 1, ifd);
    temp = temp->next;
}
close(ifd);


ifd = fopen("qwer1234.txt","rb");
temp = NULL;
temp = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
fread(temp, sizeof(struct student), 1, ifd);
start = temp;
//temp->next = NULL;
printf("%s\t%d\n",temp->name,temp->roll_num);
temp = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
/*while(fread(temp, sizeof(struct student), 1, ifd) == 1)
{

    temp->next = start;
    start = temp;
    printf("%d/n",temp->roll_num);
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct student));

}*/
close(ifd);
```

Although I am only reading a single instance for the time being, it is still not working. Nothing gets stored in the temp->name and 0 gets stored in temp->roll_num. I am stuck on it for last 4 hours. I can do it by storing elements of structure individually but wanted to do by a different way this time.

And for all those for whom it matters, this is a homework question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters,

```
close(ifd);
```

is not correct, since it isn't a descriptor, its a `FILE*`. Use:

```
fclose(ifd);
```

Since you're not flushing, unless it is a sizable list chances are nothing is written yet and you're new allocation will be the only one in the list since you have no data in your file yet.

Comment: I have no words to say to you. Its one of those moment when I think what the hell I was thinking for past so many hours. I could have used a few hours sleep. Thanks a ton mate. It really solved my problem. Bull's eye.

Comment: @Sahil no worries, sir. I didn't catch it myself until I was setting up a unit test for your code because I couldn't see anything wrong with it =P

Comment: @Sahil To test your code I needed a linked list made, a way to free it, etc. In general I needed some code you didn't have to test your code, thus I wrapped it up in some test code to do all the setup for me, then execute into your code. Nothing special. Just something someone without all your code would have to do to test *this* code. (and honeslty you should develop small test programs to do the same). Anyway, glad to help.